# Library only accessible from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to get a library to work on my Swift project via Cocoapod.
I've created a Bridging header file, and I'm importing the headers of my library in there. When I try to instantiate an object from a class of this library in my AppDelegate, I get no issues.
Trouble comes when I try to do the same thing from any other file. I have `Use of unresolved identifier 'FooBar'`.

- I've tried to import the library manually instead of using Cocoapod,
  but no luck.
- I've also tried to use a different library but I'm met with the exact
  same problem.
- XCode doesn't seem to have any problems with the Bridging file, I've
  created my own and I get no complaints at compile.

Comment: Go to your target Build Settings, Swift Compiler - Code Generation section, and make sure "Objective-C Bridging Header" is set to the header you created.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've already checked and it is (I just checked again). Plus, if it was the issue it would not let me instantiate from the AppDelegate.

Comment: Are you doing unit testing? If the class (where you are trying to use the library) in your main project is added to your test target, you will need to create a bridging header in your test target also, and add the import statement there. I have had this problem with a library I imported from Cocoapods, (though I don't think it is a problem specific to Cocoapods).

Comment: Nope no tests for now. I've also made sure that the Bridging header is only available in the build setting of my "regular" target, not at the project level or with the test target.

Comment: Check whether the class in which you are trying to use the library is included in the test target. Select the class file in the project navigator, open the Identity inspector, and look at Target Membership. Make sure the test target is not selected.

Comment: Thanks again, really helpful. I followed your advice but it only belongs to `Pods-MyProject-MyLibrary`.